# запятая в предложении с деепричастием

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед словом "сказав" в предложении: "да, вы будете правы сказав, что я простой человек".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

Если добавить `громко и ясно сказав`, то уже намного меньше сомнений, что нужно поставить запятую. А правила обособления не меняются от уменьшения/увеличения количества слов. То есть нужно использовать проверочные методы.

Все исключения обособления деепричастий здесь:

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/ne-vyidelyaetsya-zapyatyimi-deeprichastie.html